# Updates for IOS AppStore Multiplayer Game

Tags: ios, appstore, patching

I am developing a multiplayer game for the web, android and ios. For the web and android i can instantly push out new versions of my game because they support executing remotly loaded code. But with IOS i need to wait for an Apple approval taking about 10 days. I want to push updates more then weekly.

What if my server code changes so the client MUST update? Run an old version of the server code just for IOS? How do other multiplayer devs handle this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a change is introduced that is means you need to issue a client update as an "emergency bug fix", then you can apply to Apple for an expediated review. And in any case, Apple do seem a bit quicker at approving apps if the update is essentially a bug fix.

However, I would really recommend that you make your server protocol backwards-compatible. Part of the whole ethos of the way App Store updates work on iOS is that it is really up to the user when they update. Even if you manage to get an app accepted that forces the user to update, I think this would seem highly unusual to the player.

Comment: lets say i fix some kind of exploit. I DONT want ios useres to still play the exploitable version so keep  backwards-compatible server often is not really an option.

Comment: How likely is the situation where you become aware of an exploit, but cannot build into your new server code avoidance of that exploit whilst still maintaining compatibility with the old version of the protocol when used "legitimately"? But OK, if that really proves impossible, then you effectively have an "emergency" situation: so what you do is apply to Apple for an expediated review, clearly marking in the update notes that it i s an emergency security fix, and explain in the review notes why it was absolutely impossible to maintain backwards compatibility.